# Como fazer um grafico agrupado entre barras e linhas com google chart e exportar para pdf (C#, MVC)

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, mvc, google-charts

Seria algo como a imagem abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Vlw galera

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Os exemplos do site do Google Chart são bem detalhados, veja esse: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/combochart#example

Demonstra exatamente o cruzamento entre um gráfico de barras e de linhas. A geração é feita com as options abaixo:

```
var options = {
  title : 'Monthly Coffee Production by Country',
  vAxis: {title: 'Cups'},
  hAxis: {title: 'Month'},
  seriesType: 'bars',
  series: {5: {type: 'line'}}
};
```

Inclusive com exemplo no JSFiddle funcionando. O que você vai mudar obviamente é apenas os dados que são passados na variável **data**:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
     ['Month', 'Bolivia', 'Ecuador', 'Madagascar', 'Papua New Guinea', 'Rwanda', 'Average'],
     ['2004/05',  165,      938,         522,             998,           450,      614.6],
     ['2005/06',  135,      1120,        599,             1268,          288,      682],
     ['2006/07',  157,      1167,        587,             807,           397,      623],
     ['2007/08',  139,      1110,        615,             968,           215,      609.4],
     ['2008/09',  136,      691,         629,             1026,          366,      569.6]
  ]);
```

Que acredito que no seu caso venha através da WebAPI. A conversão com PDF é possível usando SVG, nesse JSFiddle aqui já tem essa implementação:

http://jsfiddle.net/zvx6eb7e/10/

Usando [CSS2PDF](http://www.cloudformatter.com/Resources/Pages/CSS2Pdf/Script/) --> xepOnline.jqPlugin.js